# Determinants and Differential Equations Problem

Tags: matrices, differential

I have a question on my homework in Differential Equations and Linear Algebra that I'm not quite sure on. Here is the background given to describe the question and the one following it:

> "[Here] we explore a relationship between determinants and solutions to a differential equation. The $3\times 3$ matrix consisting of solutions to a differential equation and their derivatives is called the Wronskian and, as we will see in later chapters, plays a pivotal role in the theory of differential equations."

This is the question following the description:

> "Verify that $y_1(x)=\cos(2x), y_2(x)=\sin(2x), y_3(x)=e^x$ are solutions to the differential equation: $y'''-y''+4y'-4y=0$, and show that $\{\{y_1, y_2, y_3\},\{y_1', y_2', y_3'\},\{y_1'', y_2'', y_3''\}\}$ is nonzero on any interval."

Now I'm really just looking for an explanation on how I would show that it is nonzero on any interval. I completed the first part, I believe, by just taking up to the third derivative for each and plugging each set in to verify an identity of 0=0 at the end. I would then put the terms into the matrix which would give me:

$$\{\{\cos(2x), \sin(2x), e^x\}, \{-2\sin(2x), 2\cos(2x), e^x\}, \{-4\cos(2x), -4\sin(2x), e^x\}\}$$

So I've gotten this far and if anyone could point me in the right direction on where to go from here it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Please use formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the Wronskian involves taking the determinant of the matrix you've calculated.  The typical formula given looks like
$$ \left| \begin{array}{ccc} a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i \end{array}\right| = a\left| \begin{array}{cc} e&f\\h&i \end{array}\right| - b\left| \begin{array}{cc} d&f\\g&i \end{array}\right| + c\left| \begin{array}{cc} d&e\\g&h \end{array}\right| $$
$$ = aei - afh - bdi + bfg + cdh - ceg.$$
When you calculate this for your matrix you'll get some *function* in $x$ (since each entry is a function in $x$).  This function is the Wronskian, and you simply examine it to make sure it is never zero.

Comment: Actually, it might be simpler than that. The question appears to me to be asking whether the matrix is non-zero, not the determinant. And this is obviously the case as $e^x$ is never 0.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Check out the Wikipedia article on Wronskians.  Their usage in determining whether a set of solutions is linearly independent relies on the determinant of the matrix.  A zero matrix would only occur if all three solutions were $y(x) = 0$.

Comment: Be that as it may, the question as stated asks to show that the matrix, not the determinant, is zero. Of course, it is likely that they really want the determinant, but that is not what the OP says.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Feel free to post your thoughts as an answer.

Comment: I posted the sum total of them in my first comment. It was just an off-hand remark that the question as asked was simpler than what you answered. I am not disagreeing with your answer at all, just noting that it goes further than the question as stated (and I've already admitted that it is most likely your interpretation is what was really intended).

Answer (score 0):

> $$\{\{\cos(2x), \sin(2x), e^x\}, \{-2\sin(2x), 2\cos(2x), e^x\}, \{-4\cos(2x), -4\sin(2x), e^x\}\}$$

This is a matrix.  You're asked to prove there is no $x$ which makes the determinant of this matrix zero.
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2x) & \sin(2x) & e^x \\ -2\sin(2x) & 2\cos(2x) & e^x \\ -4\cos(2x) & -4\sin(2x) & e^x\end{bmatrix} = 0$$